# Simple sender/reciever HL7 messaging service using WSO2

Tags: wso2, messaging, hl7, wso2-esb

I'm looking for an open-source ESB solution on implementing a Messaging service based on the HL7 protocol.
The best solution may be WSO2, thus I've just downloaded and installed the last version (4.8.0).
After the installation and configuration of the HL7 transport through the Axis repository, I've created a Proxy Services according to the documentation ([Creating an HL7 Proxy Service](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Creating+an+HL7+Proxy+Service)).

How can I, at now, test if the service is correctly implemented, by creating a simple sender/reciever?

Note: I found a [tutorial](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.it/2013/07/wso2-esb-with-hl7-sample.html), but on launching the command "ant hl7acceptor" I get the following error: Target "hl7acceptor" does not exist in project "samples".

Answer (score -2):

> How can I, at now, test if the service is correctly implemented, by
>   creating a simple sender/reciever?

Yes you can write your simple client and  server to test this.
For client you can use Hapi test tool to send messages. For server, write a simple server code in java. Check this [sample code](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.1.0/components/business-messaging/hl7/org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.samples/4.1.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/business/messaging/hl7/samples/HL7Server.java)

Comment: The question was related to WSO2 and does not involve hapi.

Comment: So, is there a method to create a client without Hapi?

Comment: you can write simple java program to send message..At the same time you can use any HL7 clients..

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing the Proxy Service by using Hapi TestPanel, and all seems to be fine!